# Trouble when updated SQL Server 2008R2 with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have updated SQL Server 2008R2 with SQL Server 2014 but when I run "SELECT @@VERSION" it still shows "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (Intel X86) Aug 19 2014 12:21:07 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)"

Anyone can tell me whats going on?

Comment: Are you sure you've updated and not just installed them side-by-side?

Comment: yes I updated and I run the SELECT @@version in SQL Management Studio 2014

Comment: Check your SQL Services and ensure you haven't installed a new instance rather than updated.

Comment: As @Nick.McDermaid said take a look in the SQL Server configuration Manager on your server to check which instances you have.